# change the href of a css link via jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<head>
<link href="foo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

can I via jquery change the href of this link from `foo.css` to `bar.css`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Html:

```
<head>
<link id="test" href="foo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the jQuery:

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").attr("href", "bar.css");
});​
```

Comment: Since <link> doesn’t technically support the id tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), does this work in all browsers and with vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 13):

```
$('link[href="foo.css"]').attr('href','bar.css');
```

have fun

Comment: Brilliant - just what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

And one more

Html:

```
<head> 
<link id="bar" href="foo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</head>
```

jQuery:

```
$("link[id='bar']").attr('href', 'bar.css');
```