# Onclick event, unable to change .CSS file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to switch CSS file with click functionality. Tried a lot but no gain :(
style2.css is not getting applied

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav li a").click(function() { 
         $("link").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));
        });     
    });  
</script>

<body>
    <ul id="nav">
       <li class="original"><a href="#" rel="css/style1.css">Original CSS</a></li>
       <li class="original"><a href="#" rel="css/style2.css">Larger Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicat: [change the href of a css link via jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829687/change-the-href-of-a-css-link-via-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-CA>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link id='mainStylesheet' href='css/styles1.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('nav a[href]').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#mainStylesheet').prop('href', $(this).prop('href'));
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='css/styles1.css'>Original</a></li>
        <li><a href='css/styles2.css'>Bigger</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Notice that I have given an ID to the `link` element, in order to specifically change the `href` property of that.

Comment: `prop(href,'')` expects absolute path, correct me if I am wrong. But you are providing relative path. And there is nothing wrong with OP's code except unknown presence of `link`

Comment: `prop` of an `a` element also returns an absolute path I believe.

Comment: Yes you are right, it will return absolute path.

Comment: no success :( earlier atleast style1.css was getting applied

Comment: I updated my answer and have successfully tested it in IE 10, Firefox, and Chrome. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it is working fine on IE8 as well :)

Answer (score 4):

A better technique is to add a class to the BODY tag and allow CSS to inherit the newly-sized text from there, instead of swapping stylesheets.

```
body {
    font-size:12px;
}

body.big {
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: Are you implying this answer based on the text "Larger Text" in his question? but it is a good thought to feed.

Comment: I would agree that this is a much better solution than calling a new css file.

Comment: I'm assuming, not implying :)

Comment: thanks for quick turnaround but that is just a sample code. I need to swap css file with huge change in css properties

Comment: This technique scales well. I've used it to re-skin entire sites. Just prefix the second styles with .big .myClass { ... } etc.

Comment: I have 2 css files which contains same classes; however, the properties are different in both the classes. my problem is, I am not able to swap the files on click event.