# How to change css href="" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change css href using js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ko" xml:lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> New Document </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="u1.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

I have to fix above code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="u1.css" type="text/css" />
```

change into

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="u2.css" type="text/css" />
```

Can I change css href in head tag?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Query for it like you would any other element using `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`.

```
document.querySelector("link[href='u1.css']").href = "u2.css";
```

Alternatively, you could also access it via `document.styleSheets` as well.

As an example:

```
// Change [href] on first stylesheet to u2.css
document.styleSheets[0].href = "u2.css";
```

Comment: In my experience, the browser ignores stuff like `document.styleSheets[0].href = "u2.css";`... Is there something you had to do to turn the browser security down on such pages?  Or perhaps modern browsers simply no longer allow it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add ID attribute to the element and replace the href attribute with javascript.

```
var link = document.getElementById('yourid');
link.setAttribute('href', 'newhref');
```

Ref:

[change the href of a css link via jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829687/change-the-href-of-a-css-link-via-jquery)