# Multi theme website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of the whole website when I click on a button. This will remain whenever I do not change. If I go to another page, the color should remain the same as what I previously selected. 
E.g. https://india.gov.in/

In the top header, when select the color black, whole website will be black until we do not change. Same I want functionality.

I have done to change the color on current but not wholw page. When I go to another page default colors is coming.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#demo-wrapper ul li').on('click', function () { var path = $(this).data('path');$('#color-switcher').attr('href', path); }); 
}); </script>

<ul class="dropdown-menu multicolors-name"> 
<li data-path="Content/theme/assets/admin/css/custom_website.css‌​">
<a href="#">Green</a></li><li data-path="Content/theme/assets/admin/css/blue.css"><a href="#" >Blue</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide your code example so we can help you

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <script>$(document).ready(function () {  $('#demo-wrapper ul li').on('click', function () { var path = $(this).data('path');$('#color-switcher').attr('href', path); }); }); </script>                                                                                                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multicolors-name"> <li data-path="Content/theme/assets/admin/css/custom_website.css"><a href="#">Green</a></li><li data-path="Content/theme/assets/admin/css/blue.css"><a href="#" >Blue</a></li></ul> and using the two CSS file as a path given in li tag

Comment: you can use `localStorage.setItem("color", "black");` which will save the value in the browser's local storage via javascript.and to retrieve the vale just use localStorage.getItem("color");

Comment: Please check my solution based on HTML5 local storage and feel free to contact me @ aaronter[at]gmail.com for code implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this, get a `master.css` file. Inside this file you can import your other css files. Like this:

```
@import 'header.css'
@import 'main.css'
```

Then you can have another `master-theme2.css` where you would import other css files. The way to change your `master.css` file is like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22445820/4673847

For keeping the theme per page, you should use `sessions` or `cookies`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with help of some css preprocessor for example LESS. Then you can loop over prepared color schema setting:

```
    .generate-widget-colors(@list) {
      .iter(length(@list));
     .iter(@index) when (@index > 0) {
    .iter(@index - 1);
    @item: extract(@list, @index);
    @key: extract(@item, 1);
    @color: extract(@item, 2);

    .color-schema-@{key} {
        color: @color;
    }

    .background-color-schema-@{key} {
        background-color: @color;
    }

    div.connect-container.wizard-schema-@{key} > div > div > div > h3 {
        color: #25414c;
    }

    div.connect-container.wizard-schema-@{key} .widget-icon {
        color: @Green;
    }`
  }
}

.generate-widget-colors(@WidgetColors);
```

This is my own example when I pass the color(key) value into this loop from my backend and all my widgets get new colors. And for saving the schema you can use browsers local storage for example or if you have an authentication then ofc store user schema in db

Answer (score 0):

in layout apply this jquery. Get the selected color value and apply it here.

```
window.jQuery("#ButtonId").click(function () 
{ 
window.jQuery('#Layoutid').css("color", "selectedcolor");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **HTML5 local storage or cookies** to achieve it. You need to store the selected color and then retrieve it on window load.

I have created a working fiddle based on HTML 5 local storage. Just select a color and reload the fiddle, the background color will remain the same as you selected.

You can switch CSS files with something like this.

```
<span class="css-selector" id="style1" data-css="path_to_style1.css">Theme 1</span>
<span class="css-selector" id="style2" data-css="path_to_style2.css">Theme 2</span>

$(".css-selector").click(function() {
    $("head link#maincss").attr("href", $(this).data("css")); //where main css is placed in head like <link rel="stylesheet" id="maincss" type="text/css" href="path_to_style1.css">
}
```

And for simple color switching, you can use this code:

```
 <div class="selector">
    <span class="color red" data-color="#990000"></span>
    <span class="color green" data-color="#009900"></span>
    <span class="color blue" data-color="#000099"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    India is a "Sovereign, Socialist, Secular, Democratic Republic" with a parliamentary system of government. This section seeks to introduce the Constitution of India, its origin, the Parliament, various Acts and Rules that govern the nation, Documents, Public Notifications, Welfare Schemes and Application Forms to avail them, apart from updates on what’s happening around us. Know the "Who's Who" of the Indian Government and check out a range of such vital information that may help you in your daily life.
    </div>

      $(document).ready(function(){

    var themeColor="#ffffff"; // define default theme color

   if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      if (localStorage.themeColor) {
        themeColor = localStorage.themeColor //get stored color
            }

            $('.content').css('background', themeColor); set stored color as background

       }

    });


    $('.selector .color').click(function(){

    themeColor = $(this).data("color");
    $('.content').css('background', themeColor); //set selected color as background

 if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.themeColor = themeColor; // store selected color
    };


    });




 .color{
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

    .red{
    background-color:red;
    }
    .green{
    background-color:green;
    }

    .blue{
    background-color:blue;
    }
```

Check it here. https://jsfiddle.net/hcfejaez/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how can I give css path beacuse I want to change    color of whole website with different color.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and if it helps, consider accepting it is as the correct answer. Feel free to contact, in case you find it difficult to implement.