# How to switch Extjs themes dynamically

Tags: sass, extjs, sencha-architect, extjs7

I am using Extjs 7.4 Modern with Sencha Architect.  I have created three themes inherited from Neptune. I would like the user to be able to select the theme. I don't mind reloading the app after they have selected the theme to use.
This has been asked before, but:

1. I could not see how to apply that answer to an app built with the architect and
2. I am looking to see if there is a more up to date answer.

Answer (score 2):

I dont't believe it is possible since Architect compiles the theme being used (scss) to css files on the resource folder.

the only option I speculate it might work, *though admittedly it won't be very efficient,* is building the application two different times, each time with a different theme, and then changing the **href** of the css files being used on the application.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445760/how-to-change-css-href-using-javascript) for more details on that last part.