# How do I replace a specific section of a href with another part when there's multiple words that section could be?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, replace

I'm sure that question makes no sense. But essentially what I'm trying to do is create themes for a mobile app. So I have a dropdown with 3 themes right now, green, blue and black white. What i'm trying to do is when you select another option from the dropdown, I want to be able to go out and find the stylesheet in the header which would look like this...

```
<link href="themes/blackwhite/mobile-stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then have it find the color of the theme, it being either black white, green or blue and replaced it with the correct name based on which option is selected..

```
 <select id="themes" class="form-control" style="border-radius: 0;">
                <option value="0" selected>Green</option>
                <option value="1">Blue</option>
                <option value="2">Black & White</option>
            </select>
```

This is what I came up with so far... now I'm trying to figure out the find and replace..

```
function themes() {
    $("#themes").change(function () {
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "0") {
                var url = document.getElementById("theme").href;
                this.url = this.url.replace('blue' || 'blackwhite', 'green');
            } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "1") {
            } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "2") {
            }
        });
    }).change();
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!! Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Alternate User-Selectable Stylesheets](https://css-tricks.com/examples/AlternateStyleSheets/).  See also https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/alternatives.en.html

Comment: Hm... this looks interesting, I'll have to look into this one to see how everything works, looks complicated. @_@

Answer (score 0):

Give your link an `id` an try this on each change:

```
$("#link_id").attr("href", "path/new_theme.css");
```

And here is an existing answer to this question:
[html - change the href of a css link via jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829687/change-the-href-of-a-css-link-via-jquery)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can make your life a bit easier if you set more descriptive values on your select, such as 'green', 'blue' and so on.

Then, you can use a regex to solve the substitution. You don't really need to know what the current value is, you can just care about the newly selected one.

Translating that into code:

```
this.url = this.url.replace(/(\/themes\/)(.*)(\/mobile-stylesheet.css)/, '$1' + $(this).val() + '$3');
```

Comment: so then the code would look like this..? I'm a little confused I think about the $1 and $3 stuff..if ($(this).attr("value") == "green") {
                    var url = document.getElementById("theme").href;
                    this.url = this.url.replace(/(\/themes\/)(.*)(\/mobile-stylesheet.css)/, '$1' + $(this).val() + '$3');
                }

Comment: Would I need to change the ending section? '$1' + $(this).val() + '$3' to correspond with whatever value its checking. So if I said if ($(this).attr("value") == "blackwhite") which is the third option, would it look like this? '$1' + '$2' + $(this).val() ??